# Uploading an entire folder with Ink Filepicker

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm attempting to add the ability to upload a folders worth of files at once with filepicker.  Our current plan is the 'Enhanced Grow' plan, so I would assume this feature is supported as part of 'Grow'.

The documentation makes it seem like I can just add 'folders: true' to the options hash when calling pickAndStore.  I've done this and I am unable to select folders when uploading.  I am using chrome Version 31.0.1650.63.  Relevent snippets of code.  Any help that can be given troubleshooting would be appreciated.

```
  opts:
    multiple: true,
    folders: true,
    key: "notthekey",
    container: 'filepickeruploader',
    services: ['COMPUTER', 'BOX', 'DROPBOX']
  init: (selectedFolder) ->
      window.filepicker.setKey(this.opts.key)
      true

  start: (disable_multiple=false) ->
    window.filepicker.pickAndStore(this.opts, {}, this.success, this.failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Support was able to answer my question:  Due to browser limitations you can't actually 'select' a folder of files via the file menu, at least with chrome.  This code, however, does work for uploading folders If you drag a folder into the area labeled: 'Drag files or folders here' (derp).